# Unknown number of buttons, how to add a different Event Action to each JavaFX

Tags: java, button, javafx, arraylist

I have a JavaFX GUI that creates and adds a number of buttons based on the number of teams, these are stored in an ArrayList, this number varies.

Each team has a list of people on a roster.

My issue is I want to write some sort of logic that without first knowing I can add a list of buttons and when clicked each will display their different rosters.

```
        Button getTeamsButton = new Button( "Load Teams and Details" );
        getTeamsButton.setOnAction( e -> {
        getTeams.scrapeTeams();
            if( !getTeams.getTeams().isEmpty() )                      
            {             

                for( int i = 0; i < getTeams.getTeams().size(); i++ )
                {
                            Button teamName = new Button( getTeams.getTeams().get(i).getTeamName()  );
        teamNamesButtons.add( teamName );
        layout1.getChildren().add( teamNamesButtons.get( i ) );

                }
```

I am able to create the buttons.

```
                getTeamsButton.setDisable( true );
                teamNamesButtons.get( 0 ).setOnAction( f -> {
                    for(int i = 0; i < getTeams.getTeams().get( 0 ).getRoster().size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(getTeams.getTeams().get( 0 ).getRoster().get( i ));
                    }
                });                    
            }
        } );
```

And if I specify which item in the list I can print the Roster, how to I explain the logic of the top button is team 0, second is team 1, etc etc?

Any advice would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but maybe this helps.

You already "know" when you create the button which index it has: the index is given by `i`. So you just have to create an event handler that references that value. The only catch here is that you can't reference a non-final variable (or a variable that can't be made final by simply adding the `final` keyword) in a lambda expression, so you may need to copy it to a final variable.

E.g.:

```
Button getTeamsButton = new Button( "Load Teams and Details" );
getTeamsButton.setOnAction( e -> {
    getTeams.scrapeTeams();
    if( !getTeams.getTeams().isEmpty() ) {             
        for( int i = 0; i < getTeams.getTeams().size(); i++ ) {
            Button teamName = new Button( 
                 getTeams.getTeams().get(i).getTeamName()  );
            teamNamesButtons.add( teamName );
            layout1.getChildren().add( teamNamesButtons.get( i ) );

            final int index = i ;
            teamName.setOnAction(evt -> {
                for (int j = 0 ; j < getTeams.getTeams().get(index).getRoster().size(); j++) {
                    System.out.println(getTeams.getTeams().get(index).getRoster().get( j ));
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

You probably don't really need the index, though; just the relevant data. You haven't shown what's actually in your lists, but assuming you have defined some kind of `Team` class, you can make this much cleaner with

```
Button getTeamsButton = new Button( "Load Teams and Details" );
getTeamsButton.setOnAction( e -> {
    getTeams.scrapeTeams();
    // the if statement here is redundant, if the list is
    // empty, the for loop will just iterate zero times....     
    for( int i = 0; i < getTeams.getTeams().size(); i++ ) {
        Team team = getTeams.getTeams().get(i);
        Button teamName = new Button(team.getTeamName());
        teamNamesButtons.add(teamName);
        layout1.getChildren().add(teamName);

        teamName.setOnAction(evt -> {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < team.getRoster().size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(team.getRoster().get( j ));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

or, using the preferred syntax

```
Button getTeamsButton = new Button( "Load Teams and Details" );
getTeamsButton.setOnAction( e -> {
    getTeams.scrapeTeams();
    for( Team team : getTeams.getTeams()) {
         Button teamName = new Button(team.getTeamName());
         teamNamesButtons.add(teamName);
         layout1.getChildren().add(teamName);

         teamName.setOnAction(evt -> {
             for (Player player : team.getRoster) {
                  System.out.println(player);
             }
         });
     }
});
```

(You shouldn't really need the `teamNamesButtons` list either... note how it's no longer needed in the code above.)

Comment: You sir are a genius, thanks very much. I couldn't even really explain myself well but you answered perfectly and your final solution is much tidier. Thanks very much for your help.